# Why dataloader is grouping the captions in wrongly manner?

Tags: torch, dataloader

When checked with my `__getitem__` function, it is giving an image, caption, and class_id properly. An Image is a tensor of size [3, 256, 256] and a caption is a *list* of 20 elements.

But when I observed the dataloader, it is grouping captions in the wrong way. The batch size is 32. So, for a batch of data, the expected components of dataloader are 32 images, 32 captions and 32 class_ids.

But the dataloader is giving 32 images, **20 captions** and 32 class_ids. **Where 20 is the max length of a caption**.

**Instead of giving 32 captions of each length 20, dataloader is giving a list of 20 tuples, each of length 32.**

Here is the code for the dataloader, I am presenting only the relevant parts of the code.

```
class Load_Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, split='train',
                 base_size=64,
                 transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.transform = transform
        .......

    def get_caption(self, sent_ix):
        # a list of strings for a sentence
        sent_caption = self.captions[sent_ix]
        if sent_caption[-1] == '<end>':
            print('ERROR: do not need END token', sent_caption)
        num_words = len(sent_caption)
        # pad with '<end>' tokens
        x = ['<end>'] * 20
        x_len = num_words
        if num_words <= 20:
            x[:num_words] = sent_caption
        else:
            ix = list(np.arange(num_words))
            np.random.shuffle(ix)
            ix = ix[:20]
            ix = np.sort(ix)
            x[:] = [sent_caption[i] for i in ix]
            x_len = 20
        return x, x_len

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        #
        key = self.filenames[index]
        cls_id = self.class_id[index]
        #
        .....
        #
        img_name = '%s/images/%s.jpg' % (data_dir, key)
        imgs = get_imgs(img_name, self.imsize,
                        bbox, self.transform, normalize=self.norm)
        # random select a sentence
        sent_ix = random.randint(0, self.embeddings_num)
        new_sent_ix = index * self.embeddings_num + sent_ix
        caps, cap_len = self.get_caption(new_sent_ix)
        
        return imgs, caps, cap_len, cls_id, key


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.filenames)
```

How to handle this?

Comment: It's hard to understand without code. Can you post your dataloader code here?

Comment: `return imgs, caps, cap_len, cls_id, key`, just an intuition, are you capturing the correct order of the return line?

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu yeah, taking in the same order. I am feeling there can be some issues with `get_caption` method.